# Create a dictionary as an attribute in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

Factory Girl allows to do something like:

```
FactoryGirl define 
  factory :post do
    content  "some content"
    styles   "styles here"
    team     1
  end
end
```

However, if I try something inside the factory block like:

```
  factory :post do
    content  "some content"
    styles   "styles here"
    team     1
    my_dictionary {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
  end
```

The my_dictionary does not get interpreted as a dictionary type. I don't know how to make a dictionary as an attribute inside FactoryGirl. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you observe comes from a syntax ambiguity in Ruby. The language uses curly braces both for defining hashes (which you call dictionaries) as well as for blocks (e.g. when using `each` loops). As you now use the hash as the only parameter to the `my_dictionary` method, it is unclear to the parser whether that opening curly brace is to be interpreted as the start of a block or a hash. In this case, Ruby defaults to the block assumption.

To enforce the interpretation as a method parameter, you can use parenthesis like so:

```
my_dictionary({'a' => 1, 'b' => 2})
```

Then, the statement can be parsed without any ambiguity. What you have here is just one of the rare cases where you can't easily omit the parenthesis for method calls.